# Tmux 2.6 mouse control not working in MacOS 10.13 Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, tmux

I'd like to be able to use my mouse to select different panes in tmux. I've had this working on previous versions of OS X, but it won't work now.

`~/.tmux.conf`

```
set -g mouse on
```

Unfortunately on MacOS 10.13 and tmux 2.6 (installed via brew), this no longer works. I've also tried `set-option -g mouse on` with no luck.

How do I make mouse control work again?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in [this answer to a StackOverflow question](https://superuser.com/a/212121/202115).

Apparently `~/.tmux.conf` is only loaded when the tmux server starts, so if you have existing sessions then you need to kill them all before the server will restart.

To check if you have existing sessions use `tmux list-sessions`

To kill all open sessions use `tmux kill kill-server`